# Formatting QR codes in Python to add logos, change colours and style

Tags: python, qr-code

So I've got some code to create a qr code using Python. However, I am unsure on how to make the eyes are black, make it so the data points are circles and add the logo correctly. Also, if there is a different coding language that would do this better I am happy to learn.

Wanted:

[image]

Code Generates:

[image]

```
import pyqrcode
from PIL import Image

url = pyqrcode.QRCode('http://www.amazon.com',error = 'H')
url.png('test.png',scale=10)
im = Image.open('test.png')
im = im.convert("RGBA")
logo = Image.open('Facebook-logo (1).png')
box = (135,135,235,235)
im.crop(box)
region = logo
region = region.resize((box[2] - box[0], box[3] - box[1]))
im.paste(region,box)
im.show()
```

Comment: Did you find a way to make a QR code like the one on top?

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**

I temporarily solved it by writing a custom function to mask the eyes for me based on the [standards for QRCode eyes](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8321072/):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
def style_eyes(img):
  img_size = img.size[0]
  eye_size = 70 #default
  quiet_zone = 40 #default
  mask = Image.new('L', img.size, 0)
  draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
  draw.rectangle((40, 40, 110, 110), fill=255)
  draw.rectangle((img_size-110, 40, img_size-40, 110), fill=255)
  draw.rectangle((40, img_size-110, 110, img_size-40), fill=255)
  return mask
```

Then combining the two images:

```
mask = style_eyes(qr_img)
final_img = Image.composite(qr_eyes_img, qr_img, mask)
final_img
```

[image: Images created and used to creat masking]

**Long answer**

I don't know of functionality for this yet but you can follow the issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode/issues/237)

I used [qrcode](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode) to generate my images instead of pyqrcode as you have there because they have the circular module functionality. You can find their documentation in the link for other styling properties.
Here is my complete code:

```
import qrcode
from qrcode.image.styles.moduledrawers import RoundedModuleDrawer
from qrcode.image.styles.moduledrawers import CircleModuleDrawer
from  qrcode.image.styles.colormasks import SolidFillColorMask
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def style_eyes(img):
  img_size = img.size[0]
  eye_size = 70 #default
  quiet_zone = 40 #default
  mask = Image.new('L', img.size, 0)
  draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
  draw.rectangle((40, 40, 110, 110), fill=255)
  draw.rectangle((img_size-110, 40, img_size-40, 110), fill=255)
  draw.rectangle((40, img_size-110, 110, img_size-40), fill=255)
  return mask

qr = qrcode.QRCode(error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H)
qr.add_data('http://www.amazon.com')

qr_eyes_img = qr.make_image(image_factory=StyledPilImage,
                            eye_drawer=RoundedModuleDrawer(radius_ratio=1.2),
                            color_mask=SolidFillColorMask(back_color=(255, 255, 255), front_color=(255, 110, 0)))

qr_img = qr.make_image(image_factory=StyledPilImage,
                       module_drawer=CircleModuleDrawer(),
                       color_mask=SolidFillColorMask(front_color=(59, 89, 152)),
                       embeded_image_path="/Facebook-logo (1).png")

mask = style_eyes(qr_img)
final_img = Image.composite(qr_eyes_img, qr_img, mask)
```

Comment: I look like the hard-coded in `style_eyes` can't recognize the eyes correctly now